# How to stop a thread that has a blocking function from easygui in python

Tags: python, multithreading, easygui

## Context

I am using the easygui library to make a simple interface for my program.

In the program, I need to start a process that takes time and the user can cancel it if he is tired of waiting.

## Code

Here is a minimal example code:

```
import easygui as eg
import threading
import time

stop_process_flag = False

def try_connection():
    global stop_process_flag
    
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        
        if stop_process_flag:
            return False
        
        # "foo" will eventually connect (return a True value)
        connected = foo()
        
        if connected:
            return True
        
def end_connection():
    global stop_process_flag
    
    stop = eg.msgbox('Click ok to stop process before completion')
    # code does not reach here if the user does not click ok in the easygui box
    if stop:
        stop_process_flag = True

# create threads
process_thread = threading.Thread(target=try_connection)
monitor_thread = threading.Thread(target=end_connection)

# start threads
process_thread.start()
monitor_thread.start()

# Wait the process to finish. It can happen due to successful completion or user cancellation
process_thread.join()

# Check if the user has clicked the ok button and ended the thread
if monitor_thread.is_alive():
    # Here i need to stop the thread to close the eg.msgbox

# code continues
```

## The goal

I want to close the msgbox if the connection is successful and the user never clicked ok to cancel the connection.

## The problem

The problem is that if the user never clicks ok, the msgbox will never return and the code will never reach any line after the msgbox line.

So I can't even add a flag to the end_connection function because there will never be a chance for the function to check it.

## Main question

How can I kill this monitor_thread "gracefully"?

Or, is there another way to achieve the desired result?

## Outro

Let me know if you need more code or information to understand something. The actual code has a lot of unnecessary things that may draw attention from the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `multiprocessing` module instead of `threading` because it allow you to terminate a process whereas thread dont do it properly.

Here is the modified code:

```
import easygui as eg
import multiprocessing
import time

stop_process_flag = multiprocessing.Value('b', False)

def try_connection(stop_process_flag):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        
        if stop_process_flag.value:
            return False
        
        connected = foo()
        
        if connected:
            return True
        
def end_connection(stop_process_flag):
    stop = eg.msgbox('Click ok to stop process before completion')
    
    if stop:
        with stop_process_flag.get_lock():
            stop_process_flag.value = True

process_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=try_connection, args=(stop_process_flag,))
monitor_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=end_connection, args=(stop_process_flag,))

process_process.start()
monitor_process.start()

process_process.join()

if monitor_process.is_alive():
    monitor_process.terminate()
    monitor_process.join()
```